# How to randomly pick an item from vector which have x property

Tags: c++11

I am looking for a way to randomly pick a vector item in which a special property has the specified value.

as an example:
I have a vector from struct `Student`

```
struct Student{
    string name;
    float x;
    float y;
    bool dropped;
};

std::vector<Student> students;
```

in this case, select a random item in which the `dropped` value is true.

what is the most efficient way to do so?

Comment: On an unrelated note, why do you need a vector of *pointers* to `Student`? Why not a vector of plain `Student` objects, like `std::vector<Student>`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Student is an example... in my real project need the reference to my objects.. but thanks i will correct it:)

Comment: As for your problem, you could create a new vector of all elements where `dropped` is `true` (here you should use a vector of (normal, non-owning) pointers), then [shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) it, and just pick the first element.

Comment: If you really need pointers then use a *smart* pointer like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` (depending on ownership of the objects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a helper function that first collects iterators to all elements matching a unary predicate and then selects one of those at random.

It could look like this:

```cpp
#include <random>

std::mt19937& prng() {
    static std::mt19937 instance(std::random_device{}());
    return instance;
}

template <class It, class UnaryPredicate>
It get_random(It first, It last, UnaryPredicate&& pred) {
    std::vector<It> iters; // to store iterators to elements matching pred

    for(;first != last; ++first) {
        if (pred(*first)) iters.push_back(first); // matching pred, store it
    } 
    if(iters.empty()) return last; // no matching elements

    // create a uniform integer distribution for [0, iters.size())
    std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> dist(0, iters.size() - 1);

    // select a random iterator and return it:
    return iters[dist(prng())];
}
```

It would then be used like this:

```cpp
auto it = get_random(students.begin(), students.end(),
                     [](Student& s) { return s.dropped; });

std::cout << "picked " << it->name << '\n';
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YrYohbefb)